# Notify QMainWindow toolbar about fullscreen mode switch

Tags: qt, qmainwindow

In `QWindow` there is a signal `windowStateChanged(Qt::WindowState)`.

I'm looking for similar signal in `QMainWindow`. Is it available?

I need it to notify toolbar about fullscreen change, as I have a checkable toolbar button which changes window to fullscreen when user clicks it. However when user changes to fullscreen bypassing the button, it shows invalid state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QMainWindow` inherits from `QWidget` where you find the [`::setWindowState(Qt::WindowStates)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setWindowState) method. In its docs, it says:

> When the window state changes, the widget receives a `changeEvent()` of type `QEvent::WindowStateChange`.

So it seems like you have to override `changeEvent()` to handle this, I don't think there is a signal.